# Prove that two functions do not intersect

Tags: calculus, functions

I have just came up with an idea for a problem to give my friends to solve, as a part of the problem this equation approaches:
$$e^{0.5x^2-x+0.5} = x^2 -2x+1 $$
I know that it has no solution because the two functions represents both sides of the equation never intersect - pluged it in desmos grapher to get the most exact scheme.

My quastion is how to prove it formally, or at least intuitivlly, because we are not able to draw the graph as exact as the grapher.
Thanks in advance :)

edit: I think that if I will check what happens to both functions in infinity from both sides of the axis it will come that the exponential function striving stronger than the parabola, so it's kind of proof.

Comment: In response to the edit, this is not in general sufficient, for example from @Jaideep's response, if instead we had $e^t = 4t$ your limiting argument would be true, but this would have an intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation reduces to :

$$e^{\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}}=(x-1)^2$$

Let $\dfrac{(x-1)^2}{2}=t ~~;t \ge 0$

Now you have to find a solution of :

$$e^t=2t$$

Now, either simply sketch a rough graph (which I would prefer) or if you want exact formal proof, than :

Construct a function : $f(t)=e^t-2t$

For it's local minima (since global minima exists where $t <0$)
$f'(t)=e^t-2=0 \implies t=\ ln 2$

$f(\ln 2) = 2-2 \ln 2 \approx 0.6 >0$

Thus, $f(t) \neq 0 ~\forall t>0$

$$\implies e^{\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}} \neq (x-1)^2 ~\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: The most precise and accurate, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $w = x^2 - 2x + 1$. Then your equation can be written as $$\exp({\tfrac{1}{2} \cdot w}) = w \implies w = 2 \log{w} $$

Finding a solution for your problem means finding $w$ such that $ w - 2 \log{w} = 0$

Now take the derivative of $h(w) = w - 2 \log{w}$ to shows its minimum is greater than 0.

Comment: It's probably better not to resort to logarithms, as then we have to make an exception for the special case $x = 1$ where $\log w$ is not defined.

Comment: To much complicated I guess, I have to explain in to high schoolers.